# Data conflict when read file

Tags: java

I have a flow: Angualr http service call API(spring boot) read file and save data in DB.

Peoblem: When httpService call api with loop, It is almost at the same time -> api read file have been conflict data of files(for one client).

Example: When api is processing file pdf A, request read file pdf B have sent, and data save in DB will conflict between file A and B. Condition check data will be conflict.
Read file pdf A: if (nonExist) -> save DB -> reset nonExist variable. But when call api with file pdf B (same time) -> nonExist variable will be not reseted -> the next time value of nonExist will be wrong.

My code below:
Controller:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Import file property ware")
    @ApiImplicitParams(value = { @ApiImplicitParam(name = "File", dataTypeClass = MultipartFile.class) })
    @PostMapping(value = URL.IMPORT_FILE, consumes = CommonConstants.CONSUME_MULTI_PART)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<Void> doUploadExchangeRateFile(
            @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file
            , @RequestParam(value = "customerId") Long customerId
            , @RequestParam(value = "importType") Integer importType,
            HttpServletRequest request) {

            propertyWareService.importFilePdf(customerId, file, request);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and service:

```
public StateReadPdfImport getListProperties(MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request, Long optCustomerId) {

    PDFTextStripper stripper;
    Boolean headerTrans = false;
    Boolean endTransaction = false;
    Boolean endBillDue = false;
    Boolean isBillDue = false;
    Boolean chkBeginning = false;
    double previousBalance;
    StringBuilder strTrans = new StringBuilder("");
    StringBuilder strBillDue = new StringBuilder("");

    int rowTrans = 0;
    int rowBillsDue = 0;

    try (PDDocument document = PDDocument.load( new File(dirFile) )) {
        int pageNumber = document.getNumberOfPages();
        PmrPropertyRequestPdf pmrPropertyRequestPdf = new PmrPropertyRequestPdf();
        pmrPropertyRequestPdf.setTransactionDetailBeginningBalance(null);
        for (int i=1; i < pageNumber + 1; i++) {
            stripper = new PropertyPdfReader();
            stripper.setSortByPosition( true );
            stripper.setStartPage(i);
            stripper.setEndPage(i);
            lines.clear();
            Writer dummy = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
            stripper.writeText(document, dummy);

            previousBalance = 0D;
            int zIndex = 1;
            for (int j = 0; j < lines.size(); j+=zIndex) {
                WordAndCoordinates wordAndCoordinates = lines.get(j);
                String line = wordAndCoordinates.getWord();
                if (!isBillDue) {
                    if (line.equals("Property Cash Summary")
                            && wordAndCoordinates.getTextPosition().get(0).getFontSizeInPt() == 12.0) {
                        pmrPropertyRequestPdf.setNameAndAddress(lines.get(j-1).getWord().trim());
                    } else if (checkHeader(lines, j)) {
                        this.setHeaderTransDetail(lines, j, lstHeaderTransDetail);
                        headerTrans = true;
                        zIndex = 8;
                    } else if (headerTrans) {
                        if (line.contains(TransactionConstants.BEGINNING_CASH_BALANCE) && !chkBeginning) {
                            //reset chkBeginning = true, but in the next acces it is false
                            chkBeginning = true;
                            pmrPropertyRequestPdf.setTransactionDetailBeginningBalance(previousBalance);
                        }
                    } else if (line.equals(TransactionConstants.BILLS_DUE) && checkHeaderBillDue(lines, j + 1)) {
                        this.setHeaderTransBill(lines, j+1, lstHeaderTransBill);
                        isBillDue = true;
                        zIndex = 5;
                    }
                } else {
                    zIndex = 1;

                }
            }

            if (StringUtils.isBlank(pmrPropertyRequestPdf.getNameAndAddress())) {
                continue;
            }

            if (endTransaction) {
                this.setTransactionDetail(strTrans, pmrPropertyRequestPdf, transactionTypeMap, previousBalance, lstHeaderTransDetail, positionMap);
                //reset chkBeginning= false after save data of a page of PDF file to DB
                chkBeginning = false;
            }
            lines.clear();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Map<String, Object> error = OhaCommonUtil.setFileException(file);
        throw new OhaApplicationException(error, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, ex.getMessage());
    }
    return ...;
}
```

I tried google but I'm stuck and can not find anything solution!

May you help me ?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by "data conflict"? Please be more specific. What do the files mean. What is saved in DB and for what use? What is the trouble in saving data from two different files - how do they conflict?

Comment: It is hard to understand the exact problem, maybe because of language. Ideally you should have no fields, just local variables, so no mixups can happen with parallel access.

Comment: Hi @RealSkeptic ,Joop Eggen.. I have updated question. Thanks for your time!

Comment: Still 0 line of code, and still 0 explanation of what the code is supposed to do and what it does instead. We don't know anything about your requirements and your code if you don't post them.

Comment: Ah, so you have a common variable somewhere. That's not good. Please include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: It seems you are facing a concurrency problem using a common variable. You might want to check about [Java concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) to see how synchronize two thread (one per API request)

Comment: Thanks @AxelH, I'm checking

Comment: I have updated code for my case.